# Wordpress wp_get_archives function not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use Wordpress function:

```
<?php  wp_get_archives(); ?>
```

But it gives no results. It worked yesterday, but I probably accidentally did something and now It's not working anymore. No, Im not deleted all the posts, I'm not deleted archive.php page. What could I do? Maybe there is some "archive - turn off" option in admin panel?

Comment: Are you passing the function any arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Try some parameters and see if you can get them to work: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives